# Merge Numbers Textarea Automatic

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
123456 12-12 3456
```

How do I automatically convert the text into the Textarea field?

```
123456 | 12 | 12 | 3456
```

automatically corrected.
How can I do this in Textarea?

Comment: I am wrong.
I forgot to tell you this.
4543590731224248 07/20 988
This way the event is happening or in this way.
4543590731224248 07/2020 988 
---
2020 or 20 
be able to.

Comment: Total : 23 or 25 character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) event listener on your textarea and modifying it's content by splitting based on 1 or more non-digit characters and joining them with your desired pipe(`|`) symbol.

```js
document.getElementById('some_id').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
   var content = this.value.split(/[^\d]+/);
   this.value = content.join(" | ");
});
```

```html
<textarea rows='10' cols='50' id='some_id'>
</textarea>
```

Ok, so as discussed in the comments, for your credit card formatting, you can do something like below:

```js
document.getElementById('some_id').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
       
       var content = this.value;
       var new_content = '';
       var temp_content = '';
       var current_length = 0;
       for(var i=0;i<content.length;++i){
           if('0123456789'.indexOf(content.charAt(i)) != -1){
               temp_content += content.charAt(i);
               current_length++;
           }
           
           if(current_length === 25){
              new_content += insertPipeForCreditCardFormat(temp_content) + '\n';
              temp_content = '';
              current_length = 0;
           }
       }
       this.value = new_content + temp_content;
});

function insertPipeForCreditCardFormat(credit_card){
   var pipe_indices = new Set([16,18,22]);
   var card_format = '';
    for(var i=0;i<credit_card.length;++i){
      if(pipe_indices.has(i)){
        card_format += '|';
      }
      card_format += credit_card.charAt(i);      
    }
    return card_format;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='some_id' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192175/discussion-on-answer-by-vivek-23-merge-numbers-textarea-automatic).

Comment: @vivek_23 are you here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`:

```js
 

const str = "123456 12-12 3456";
const replaced = str.replace(/\-|\s/g, " | ");
console.log(replaced);
```